# Device or resource busy when try to delete directory from running container

Tags: docker, jenkins, docker-compose

Accidentally i have created script.sh directory instead of script.sh file. but when I try to delete that directory from container it says device busy.how to delete directory from containers.
it shows

rm: cannot remove '/tmp/script.sh/': Device or resource busy

Comment: You mounted it?

Comment: I'd delete and recreate the container, doubly true if deleting the directory confused the main container process.

Comment: seems like file is open by some some process. Can you run "lsof +D /full_path" ? Then grab the pid of the process that is holding the directory. Use the pid to kill the process with command "kill -9 pid" and then run "rf -rm /full_path"